# Contaminants in very old water pipes?

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet

Suppose they're 100 years old and metal - unsure if iron, lead, or neither - and inflowing water *before* the pipes is clean. What contaminants are expected in tap water from such pipes? Heavy metals? Asking for sake of countertop water filters.

Comment: 100 year old, I would be thinking of replacing the pipes before getting a filter.  Most metal pipes are at or pass end of life.  When a city water pipe breaks and needs replacing, 9 times out ten it is an old(50 to 100 year) pipe.  Those pipes are big and thick, not the thin pipes in houses.  House pipes are easy for a home owner to replaced, just remove pipe and add new pipe, not much planning where to place pipes.

Comment: When replacing those pipes,it would probably be a good idea NOT to look inside them.

Comment: @crip659 Agreed but not an option in this case. On looking, it's that bad? Is countertop water filtration futile?

Comment: Soon(maybe a couple/few years) you will not be given the option to not replace.  Fortunately you do have the option to do it in small sections now.  The 100 year build up inside the pipes is basically stuck to the pipes, just looks yucky.  Clean looking water can have sediments(hard water) in it, so filtration is not futile, but if wanting good filters should have water tested to see what you need to filter out.  Probably a good chance the pipes will develop pin holes leaks instead of just breaking in half.

Comment: Ah, mineral build up might be a good thing - keeps the water away from the metal pipe. Municipalities with lead pipes in play adjust the water chemistry to keep lead from leaching, unless they are the bozos who took over the Flint water plant and didn't bother to do that.

Comment: Let's say the nation in question would sooner let the whole building crumble, and a test kit can't be easily acquired, so I just need general information. Interesting point @Ecnerwal

Comment: Can’t answer the specific question, but would suggest getting into the habit of running water down the drain for a couple of minutes each morning. This will increase the lifespan of your filter (assuming it picks up the supply close to the faucet).